# Centro Sperimentale di Cinema

Tags: education

I have a question in particular for Italian sound designers.

I have been admitted to the last exam in order to become a student of the three years course as "Tecnico del suono" into the "Centro sperimentale di Cinema di Cinecittà". The problem is that the selection will be at the end of 4 weeks of preliminal lessons. In order to follow this lessons I should leave my work, very well paid, in a radio here in Rome.

What I'm trying to explain is that in one hand I have a very good work, in the other hand the possibility (only half of people will enter) of studying and working in the most important school of cinema here in Italy...
So, if you were in my mind what would you do?
What kind of information do you have about "Centro sperimentale". Is it a good school as everybody says?

Answer (score 1):

Ciao Francesco

I'm from Italy and work and live in Rome. 
What do you expect from the courses at the CSC? Are you looking into production sound recording, editing, re-recording?

Personally, I know lots of people working in the industry that didn't attended that courses (I'm one of those), but I have friends of mine that come from there. It's one of a kind school here in Italy, I think that it's a real interesting and engaging place to study in, but... I think that it's tied to a old/classic way of making movie that should be left behind: there are no classes that teaches sound effects editing, for instance. Maybe things will change in the next academic year...

If you like to have a chat in italian, write me at    d [dot] f [at] me [dot] com

a presto e in bocca al lupo

Davide

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for answering! What you are telling me is a kind of problem that many people indicates. As a matter of fact I have to think about it. Although I think that I will attend the last exam and I'll try to have a place in the school. If I'll be able to get into I think that I'll keep your pieces of advice in order to study what I don't find there in some other place.

Crepi il lupo!

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know, in Italy we have no laws. You could have no degrees and make any fabulous job or have dozen of degrees and find yourself with no job. 
My advice: keep your job at the radio, give a look at the CSC programs and study what you still don't know (trying to make some practice too) and propose, to the radio staff, to experiment (where possible) the results of your new learnings . You coul'd have an advancement or be noticed elsewhere in some way.
Good luck
Fabio